# Input Parameters Name and Types for complicated WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soapui

Is there a way to get all Input Request Parameters and Output Request parameters for the complicated WSDL (complex type) as follows. I can generate SOAP request but I can not get type of the parameters. Could anyone help?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Operation;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request.SubmitException;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.SoapUIException;

public class TestWsdl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException, SubmitException {
        try {
            String wsdl = "https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService19?wsdl";

            WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
            WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project, wsdl, true)[0];

            Map<String, Operation> m = iface.getOperations();

            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : m.entrySet()) {
                WsdlOperation operation = (WsdlOperation) entry.getValue();
                WsdlRequest request = operation.addNewRequest("My request");
                request.setTimeout("2000");
                String requestContent = operation.createRequest(true);
                request.setRequestContent(requestContent);
                if("createUser".equalsIgnoreCase(operation.getBindingOperationName())){
                    System.out.println("REQUEST: " + requestContent +"\n\n");
                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {                
        }
    }

}
```

SOAP Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://api.echosign" xmlns:dto="http://dto.api.echosign">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <api:createUser>
             <api:apiKey>?</api:apiKey>
             <api:userInfo>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:company>?</dto:company>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:customField1>?</dto:customField1>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:customField2>?</dto:customField2>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:customField3>?</dto:customField3>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:email>?</dto:email>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:firstName>?</dto:firstName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:groupKey>?</dto:groupKey>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:lastName>?</dto:lastName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:optIn>?</dto:optIn>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:password>?</dto:password>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:phone>?</dto:phone>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <dto:title>?</dto:title>
             </api:userInfo>
          </api:createUser>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `wsdl` should contain either an inline `xml schema` or referencing to an external xml schema.

You may create java classes for the same xml schema using `jaxb`, `xmlbeans` etc., whatever you are comfortable with.

Then it would be easy for you to create the request with data types.

Of course, the above request would in object form of your request type, serialize it to string once soap headers are added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for on-the-fly solution without creating java classes. I will be perfect If I can product similar to what SOAPUI does.